# Why is the time consumed so different at different "scroll" times in elasticsearch "term query"

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, I used **term query** to search some entries. However, when the search results are large (about 4700 entries), the "term query" cost too much time (about 8 min). Meanwhile, the time consumed is quite different at different batched of **scroll**. I create a line chart to show the difference. The x-axis of the chart is the number of **scroll** (0 is the first time running scroll). The y-axis is the time consumed.

[image]

**Why is the time consumed so different at different "scroll" times in elasticsearch "term query"?**

my doc looks like

```
{
    "id": "doc1"
    "text": "AAAAABBBBHHHHHKAAAAAAAAAAUUUUUKAAAAAAAAAAAK"
}
```

the field **text** has a analyzer that split the string after the letter **K**

I want to search all doc that contain the term **AAAAABBBBHHHHHK** and my java search code is

```
SearchResponse response = esClient.prepareSearch("my_index")
                .addSort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
                .setScroll(new TimeValue(60_000))
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("text", "AAAAABBBBHHHHHK"))
                .setSize(100)
                .get();
do {
            for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits()) {
                 ......
            }
            response = esClient.prepareSearchScroll(response.getScrollId())
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(60_000))
                    .get();
        } while (response.getHits().getHits().length != 0);
```

**In addition, I also want to know is there any method to optimize search perform to cut down the search time?**

NOTE:

- elasticsearch version: 6.6.1
- elasticsearch jvm config
- the index shard: 1 shard, no replica, the shard size is 74GB (currently, I only have one server)

```
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on here but going to comment that if a simple term query is taking 8 minutes at <5000 records, you have a serious config issue.

Comment: @bryan60 the first 16 times is quick, and then it became slower and slower